# Replace while matching in MySQL

Tags: mysql

table `artists`

```
id | name
---------
1  | kida
2  | capital t
3  | taylor swift
```

```
select replace(name, ' ', '') from artists where match(`name`) against ('taylorswift' IN BOOLEAN MODE) limit 1
```

If I run this query it shows no result, but I want to replace space with null and show Taylor Swift as a result. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would `taylor swift` ever match on `taylorswift`? By what magic should MySQL decide that that space is irrelevant for searching? Would you expect Google to return meaningful results if you search for `usebooleansearchmatchinginmysql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `taylorswift != taylor swift`. Your main idea is to display the `name` without space. You can do like

```
select replace(name, ' ', '') as name
from artists 
where match(`name`) against ('taylor swift' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
limit 1;
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'replace(name, ' ', '')) against ('taylorswift' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
limit 1' at line 3 
@Rahul

Comment: @rexhin, may be you can't use function in `match` context. Try the second version in my answer.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes @Rahul

Comment: @rexhin, Yes, was wrong. You will have to search the way it's indexed. See edited answer.

Comment: Sorry we need to search against 'taylorswift' not 'taylor swift' @Rahul

Comment: @rexhin, in that case use normal search like `where replace(name,' ','') = 'taylorswift'` instead of fulltext search.